What is a fast way to convert a very large string to an integer?
I looking for a very fast way to convert a large string to an integer. The int function is very slow for the string I want to convert - I used sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0) to remove the limit for int conversion. My string consists of numbers only (without decimals).

I don't think there is a faster way than the int function, if there was, it would have been built in.

How large is the string, how long does it take, and what Python version are you using?

What are you going to do with the integer?

@mkrieger1 That's completely different. Converting a billion small ones really has nothing to do with converting one very large one.

Silly as it looks, on my PC I can convert a sufficiently long string to an integer faster by recursively cutting it into pieces and eventually using the built-in int(someString) function than by going straight for int(someString) from the start.
def parsestr_rec(string):
    l = len(string)
    if l < 10000:
        return int(string)
    return parsestr_rec(string[0:l//2]) * pow(10, l - l//2) + parsestr_rec(string[l//2:])

For example with this,
someLongString = ""
for i in range(40000):
    someLongString += str(i)
sys.set_int_max_str_digits(0)
print(int(someLongString) == parsestr_rec(someLongString), len(someLongString))
%timeit int(someLongString)
%timeit parsestr_rec(someLongString)

I got:
True 188890
118 ms ± 1.57 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)
41 ms ± 206 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

For longer strings it can save more time.
True 488890
784 ms ± 11.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
192 ms ± 1.83 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10 loops each)

This was benchmarked with Python 3.8.17 (default, Jul  5 2023, 20:35:33) [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)]
Here are some other results with python 3.11, using print(timeit.timeit(lambda: int(someLongString), number=10)) and a similar thing for the other function.
True 188890
1.1809259860001475
0.30092264199993224

True 488890
7.696646332
1.4288414500001636

In python 3.12 the built-in wins:
True 188890
0.24467968499999415
0.29273804200002473

True 488890
1.1080191049999826
1.346453720999989


Python itself very much improved that in 3.11 or 3.12, so try the current version as well.

@nocomment that's reasonable and I'm trying to do it, I'm not ignoring your comment, but it's not that easy to just update python. I mean I've installed something but the version I'm running hasn't changed, that sort of fun thing.

Ok :-) Btw you might want to use someLongString = "".join(map(str, range(40000))), which is faster.

This algorithm was implemented in the CPython 3.13 release. See: https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/90716

@blhsing With some more optimizations, and I believe it was in 3.12.
